# What would be a "lark" or "early bird" in Latin

Tags: classical-latin, idiom, word-request

Inspired by this question [What would be a "night owl" in Latin?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5349/what-would-be-a-night-owl-in-latin) and its excellent answers, I's like to know about the antonym of a "night owl": What would be a "lark" or "early bird"?

I was thinking about formations like *homo matutinus* or *homo matutinalis*, but for sure, there are better alternatives!

Comment: I wonder if you could do something with the goddess names *Mater Matuta* or *Aurora*.

Comment: Well *matutinus* would mean exactly that. It has given *matineux* or *matinal* in French by the way.

Comment: In *Etymologies* XII.7.37, it is the Nightingale *Lucinia,* or *Credula,* which is the 'early bird' and welcomes the sun as it rises. Just in case you need a symbolic early bird.

Comment: @luc _matutino_ is a valid word in Spanish, translatable as the English adjective 'morning'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My suggestion is to simply use the adjective *matutinus* either alone or with an appropriate noun.
The entry in [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=matutinus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) gives examples in the right spirit:

- *cliens matutinus* — a client who comes early in the morning
- *Aeneas se matutinus agebat* — Aeneas was up early
- Iuppiter and Ianus were greeted early in the morning

A morning person would be aptly called *homo matutinus* in Latin.
There may be something more colorful, but this is certainly an idiomatic choice.